# How do I solve HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found error in Windows 10 whilst trying to load phpmyadmin?

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

I am currently using Xampp for my Apache Web Server on Windows 10 I have successfully got it working as shown in the image below which can be accessed clicking on the link :-
[Xampp Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHW1i.png)

Furthermore I am trying to implement phpmyadmin so I can start to create a database for my application. I have installed it using the phpmyadmin.net website, I have also extracted it to the root directory of my xampp folder xampp/htdocs. However when trying to load it either by 127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin or localhost/phpmyadmin. It comes up with the error in the link:-
[Not Found Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSMjK.png)

Any ideas that will help me get this working would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

XAMPP comes with an installed version of phpMyAdmin; I wonder if the pathname is conflicting. Try renaming the folder of your phpMyAdmin to something else, like "pma-4.5.5.1" and try loading that URL instead.

Furthermore, your control center is showing some oddities about your MySQL installation; do you have two MySQL server instances installed? In one pane it states that a MySQL is already running on 3306, in another pane it's showing that the XAMPP MySQL server is configured to run on 3307. This seems odd to me.

Finally, does Apache actually work? What happens if you try to load http://localhost/ itself?

Comment: Hi I have tried renaming the folder with htdocs and tried again to load the URL however it is still saying cannot be found. I did have some problems getting Xampp to work on Windows 10 when I first installed it firstly with the Apache I had to to some configuration within the httpd.conf file to get it to connect which included changing port numbers from 8000 to 8080.

Comment: I also did further changes to the my.ini file to get MySQL working on Xampp however it kept on failing due to no MySQL server being installed on my O/S. I then installed the server from the MySQL website and did further changes to port settings which made PID and Port come into effect on Xampp.

Comment: Finally when I load http://localhost it comes up with "ISS Windows Welcome Screen" - What can I do to make the appropriate corrections to get MySQL and phpMyAdmin to work properly ?

Comment: XAMPP comes with a bundled MySQL installation, so it's really strange that you had trouble with that aspect. What happens if you load `http://localhost:8080` ? Looks like IIS is handling port 80, which is fine (since IIS and Apache can coexist as long as they're using different ports, which it seems yours are).

Comment: Hi Isaac, When I type in the http://localhost:8080 it comes up with the Welcome to Xampp dashboard page. Where do I go from there ?

Comment: Hi I have got phpMyAdmin up finally would the two different port numbers for MySQL bring trouble connecting to a database from application ?

Comment: The symptoms of that problem would (in rough order of likeliness to occur) be that your application would be unable to connect at all (since the username/password wouldn't exist in the second database server) or would give an error about the database or table missing, or simply not have the expected data present. Since you weren't able to connect to the XAMPP-provided MySQL instance, it's questionable whether it's even functional so you might be fine.